# Getting "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)" when trying to destroy an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, destroy

I’m having trouble destroying an object in Rails (using Rails 4.2.3).  This line in the below code

```
user_my_object_time_match.destroy
```

is failing with the error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

this is being deleted in a transaction in another model, if that matters.  Below is the surrounding transaction

```
  def delete_my_object_and_any_matching_records
    transaction do
      linked_my_object = self.linked_my_object
      if destroy
        if !linked_my_object.nil?
          user_my_object_time_match = UserMyObjectTimeMatch.joins(:my_object_time).where("my_object_time_id = ?", linked_my_object.my_object_times[0])
          if !user_my_object_time_match.nil?
            user_my_object_time_match.destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `destroy_all` if you are destroying a ActiveRecord Relation (a collection of objects). `destroy` is just for destroying a single object or a list of objects by `id`.

More information here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all and http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy.

They are similar but subtly different. Also keep in mind there is `delete` and `delete_all` which are faster than their `destroy` counterparts but don't call callbacks.